# Mule ESB, how to add up a set of numbers within a JSON array

Tags: json, mule, esb, jsonpath

I have a Database Connection returning something that looks like this (after the Object-to-JSON Transformer:

```
C:\curl>curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d     @input3.txt http://localhost
:8081/mule/getNum

[{"F1":111},{"F1":222},{"F1":444}]
```

Please note the JSON statements are contained within a JSON array.

Given the above structure, how do I add up all of the numeric fields in the second column of the array?  Which node would I use, Other than a SEELCT SUM() from the DB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `message.payload` is the `List<Map>` produced by the DB inbound endpoint, you can do this:

```
<expression-component>
  sum = 0;
  foreach (row : message.payload) {
    sum += row['F1'];
  }
  message.payload = sum;
<expression-component>
```